# PHP to serial with weird baud rates

Tags: php, serial-port, baud-rate

I am trying to use PHP to send text to an LED sign so I can send support ticket numbers to it. The sign itself is a piece of work; it came from eBay and is poorly made with almost no documentation. After fiddling with it for a while, I was able to figure out the way it expected stuff to be sent to it and that the baud rate is 28800. I already know how to communicate with stuff like this using PHP, but I don't know how to change the baud rate to something nonstandard. I've tried other baud rates, and haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: I can use windows or Linux, but I've done php serial communication in linux before, so I prefer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the setserial command in Linux - with it, you can assign a serial port to have a non-standard rate.

You should be able to pull it off if you run setserial as follows before connecting to initialize the port (either in the server init scripts or in your PHP...though not sure if that'd be a good idea):

`/bin/setserial /dev/ttyS1 spd_cust baud_base 115200 divisor 4`

Here's what's going on in the command:

- The spd_cust option tells the OS to set the speed to a custom divisor when the application requests 38400.
- /dev/ttyS1 is the serial port. You'll change this to whatever.
- The baud_base is the number to be used by the divisor 4

115200 / 4 = 28800 ...the speed you need :-)

In your PHP code, you'll connect at 38400, which seems strange, but because of setserial, the port you specify will be running at 28800

Answer (score 1):

## For windows try

`"mode " . $device . " BAUD=" . $baud`

## For linux try

`"stty -F " . $device . " " . $baud`

I think these are the correct commands to send

Comment: The PHP serial class is based on stty. The problem is that it throws an error when you try to specify a baud rate that isn't one of the standard speeds (2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, etc)

Comment: Have you tried to modify the stty program to accept your baudrates, Take a look here, http://mhonarc.axis.se/dev-etrax/msg06754.html

Comment: I've done stuff in C before, but I've never tried modifying something like this. I found this:
http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9jb2Rhc2UuYy9za2tmZXAtMC44NmMvd29yay9za2tmZXAvc3R0eS5j&lang=c
which appears to be the source for stty, but after looking through it, I don't know how to make it accept new baud rates. Is there anywhere that I could learn more about how do do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two links

- http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=8658A
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html (Can send data to the "COM1" for windows and so on.)

Comment: I know about the serial class, but it won't let you use 28800 as the baud rate.